# How do I substitute an expression into another?

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to substitute equation (1) to equation (2) in a way that mathematica chooses the best and simpliest form of a result.

To clarify the problem and make it less generic, here is the specifics of the problem:

My equation (1) is defined by:

$$\cos(\lambda_r)\cosh(\lambda_r) +  \frac{\lambda_r M_t}{mL}[\cos(\lambda_r)\sinh(\lambda_r) - \sin(\lambda_r)\cosh(\lambda_r)] - \frac{\lambda_r^3I_t}{mL^3}[\cosh(\lambda_r)\sin(\lambda_r)+\sinh(\lambda_r)\cos(\lambda_r)]+\frac{\lambda_r^4M_tI_t}{m^2L^4}[1-\cos(\lambda_r)\cosh(\lambda_r)]=-1$$

My Equation (2) is defined by:

$$A_r = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4Lm + 4M_t\{ \cos(\lambda_r)-\cosh(\lambda_r) + \varsigma_r[\sin(\lambda_r)-\sinh(\lambda_r)]\}^2 + \frac{4I_t\lambda_r^2}{L^2}\{[\sin(\lambda_r)+\sinh(\lambda_r)]^2 - \varsigma_r[\cos(\lambda_r)-\cosh(\lambda_r)][\sin(\lambda_r) + \sinh(\lambda_r)] + \varsigma_r^2[\cos(\lambda_r) +\cosh(\lambda_r)]^2\} + \frac{Lm}{\lambda_r}\{ -\sin(2\lambda_r)(-1 + \varsigma_r^2) + 4\cos(\lambda_r)\sinh(\lambda_r)(-1+\varsigma^2)-4\sin(\lambda_r)[2\varsigma_r\sinh(\lambda_r) + \cos(\lambda_r)(1+\varsigma_r^2)] +2\sinh(\lambda_r)[2\varsigma_r\sinh(\lambda_r)+\cosh(\lambda_r)(1 + \varsigma_r^2)]\}}}$$

and I would like mathematica to find the best way to insert equation (1) in the subquotient's square root of equation (2).

I already tried the command Collect[] but it doesn't result as I would like,

```
fullsolCol = 
 Collect[subquotientSR, (Subscript[\[Lambda], r]*Subscript[M, t])/(m*
     L), ((Subscript[\[Lambda], r]^3)*Subscript[\[CapitalIota], 
     t])/(m*(L^3)), ((Subscript[\[Lambda], r]^4)*
     Subscript[\[CapitalIota], t]*Subscript[M, t])/((m^2)*(L^4))]
```

where `subquotientSR` is the expression inside the square root of equation's (2) subquotient.

I also tried the FullSimplify command with assumption, like:

```
FullSimplify[fullsol, (Cos[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*
     Cosh[Subscript[\[Lambda], 
      r]] + ((Subscript[\[Lambda], r]*Subscript[M, t])/(m*L))*(Cos[
         Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*Sinh[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]] - 
       Sin[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*
        Cosh[Subscript[\[Lambda], 
         r]]) - (((Subscript[\[Lambda], r]^3)*
         Subscript[\[CapitalIota], t])/(m*(L^3)))*(Cosh[
         Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*Sin[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]] + 
       Sinh[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*
        Cos[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]) + (((Subscript[\[Lambda], r]^4)*
         Subscript[\[CapitalIota], t]*Subscript[M, 
         t])/((m^2)*(L^4)))*(1 - 
       Cos[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]]*
        Cosh[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]])) = -1]
```

but mathematica gives an error saying that the assumption is not valid.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by saying "substitute one equation into another"? Do you want to eliminate some variable? Do you see in eq.2 some combinations that can be reduced to 1 according to eq.1 ?? It is not  clear. Further advice: work without subscripts here. They may disturb the way Mma makes the simplifications.

Comment: Yes, once more: avoid `Subscript`; it's for pretty-printing, but it causes more messes than it's worth in calculations. Also, have you seen [`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html), in case that's what you need?

Comment: What happens in your `FullSimplify[fullsol,...Cosh[Subscript[\[Lambda], r]])) = -1]` if you change that `=` to `==`? If that doesn't accomplish your goal then please edit your post to include `equation1=...MathematicaCode...` and `equation2=...MathematicaCode...`